# log" could not be opened: failed to open stream: Permission denied

Tags: troubleshooting

The stream or file "/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/laravel/storage/logs/laravel-2019-05-18.log" could not be opened: failed to open stream: Permission denied

Comment: The question is unclear: you should give to the community more details on what you are trying to do. For example: on what kind of system are you trying to install what?

Answer (score 0):

The file is likely only readable by the root account.

Prefix your command with `sudo` and try again.  For example:

```
sudo nano /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/laravel/storage/logs/laravel-2019-05-18.log
```